# Vector<Vec3b> difference with Vector<int> in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, vector

My project is about the moving puck detection and location finding on hockey table. I need to use `HoughCircles` to detect the circular form of the puck.
But for this hough alghoritm I need to make a `Vector`. I am familiar with `Vector` concept and how it is working ( basic), but there is problem of differentiating for example `Vector<int> Vec` and `Vector<Vec3b> Vec`.

Is it possible to somebody let me know what is their difference in meaning and application?

Comment: I posted an answer. If you need more details you should explain better what you want to do, why you need them, and better with a small code sample

Comment: Dear Miki Thank you so much, It was clear and very helpful. I saw this kind of vector definition in text books and other tutorials, I was expecting while definition of VECTOR, we define the type and name of VECTOR, so I got confused with this new name while VECTOR definites I asked from you guys if could help me about this kind of definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention that `Vector` and `vector` are different. `vector` is `std::vector`, while `Vector` is `cv::Vector`. Even if in practice the difference is minimal, they are really different things.

I'll assume you meant `std::vector`, but in this context this is valid also for `cv::Vector`.

---

A `vector<int>` is a vector of integers. Nothing fancy about this.

A `vector<Vec3b>` is a vector of `cv::Vec3b`, which is an OpenCV structure that holds 3 `uchar` (`unsigned char`), i.e. a type with 8 bit that can contain data from 0 to 255. It is in fact defined as a `cv::Vec_<uchar, 3>`. [cv::Vec](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec) is a template class that represents short numerical vectors, up to 4 elements, but this is not important here.

A `Vec3b` is usually used in OpenCV to store the color for a pixel, usually a B,G,R triplet.

Comment: Couldn't put it any better myself. Also refer to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec) for the definition of `Vec3b` and `Matx`.